# Is this diagram in my textbook not constructed to scale?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage

Or am I having an illusion.
[image]

Clearly, the distance from 6v to 4v is not the same as 4v to 2v. 
I know it should be based on: $V = k\frac{q}{r}$.

Comment: The distances are different as they should be. $V\propto 1/r$ is not a linear relationship: $1/2 - 1/4 = 1/4$ whereas $1/4 - 1/6 = 1/12 \neq 1/4$.

Comment: @march, but if you double r, the distance from the center of the sphere, V should be halved. I know I made a mistake by not measuring from the center. But the distance from the center to 6v is clearly not equal to half the distance from the center to 3v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the diagram in the book is not to scale. It should look like this:
[image]
Each transition increases by 1V. The outer edge would have a potential of 1V, the transition between green and yellow would have a potential of 2V. The final transition has a potential of 6V.

Comment: Can you label them please.

Comment: @user132522 Done.

Comment: Sorry @LDC3, too few credit to vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Should it? Lets say the 6V mark  is at distance at 1, then 4V is at 1.5 and 2V is at 3 meaning that 4V should be in in the middle between the origin and the 2V mark, which could work as far as i can tell on my screen

Comment: Ohhh, so it's from the very center!

Comment: yes $r$ is referring to the center of the charge (fun fact: for points outside the charge it does not matter whether its a point charge, a hollow sphere, a massive sphere or whatever)

Comment: But how do you explain that the distance from the center to 6v is not half the distance from the center to 3v???